# Set limit bandwidth on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm going to use EC2 as test machines, and I have test scenario where I need bandwidth limit. So I'm wondering is there a way to set bandwidth limit using Java API for EC2, maybe using ELB or ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function in AWS to limit bandwidth on EC2, ELB or other services.

The only real bandwidth limitation is based on the Amazon EC2 **Instance Type**. Basically, the bigger the instance type, the bigger the bandwidth. However, AWS does not publish the specific bandwidth available to each instance type.

You might be able to do something in the Operating System, but this would be unrelated to the fact that the OS is running on AWS.

Answer (score 0):

But, you can manage the bandwidth for your Gateway. Please refer to this [AWS official link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/latest/userguide/MaintenanceUpdateBandwidth-common.html)

Comment: That's a doc for the storage gateway, not everybody has one in their cabinet.

Answer (score 0):

If your servers use Linux, enable Traffic Control (tc) or you can setup your own gateway with tc.
In windows 10  - https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/tools-limit-bandwidth/